# jQuery filter asterisk (*) input

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have here a jQuery code that filter special characters:

```
$("#txtFName").keyup(function () {
      name = $("#txtFName").val();
      name = name.replace(/[^a-zA-Z 0-9.]+/g, '');
      $("#txtFName").val(name);
});
```

But I only wanted to filter the asterisk (*) character and the remaining are allowed. What adjustment should I do in `/[^a-zA-Z 0-9.]+/g` to make this? Or there are other work around to do this? Thank you very much!

Comment: Why not just prevent input of an asterisk in the keypress event (test the keycode and return false or preventDefault)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So you only need to replace `*`:

```
$("#txtFName").keyup(function () {
  $(this).val($(this).val().replace(/\*/g, ''));
});
```

Comment: Great idea. Though I adjust the code accordingly. Code: `name.replace(/\*/g, '');`